# Designing creative databases and maintaining efficiency

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design

I'm developing an app, and I have a list of posts for which I would like to collect how many views that each post got.
My first idea was to update each item every time it was viewed but if I were to view a few at once I might lose data.
My second idea was to create a separate chart and to add to it each time a post is viewed, but this wouldn't have efficient time and space complexity.
Does anyone have any other ideas?  For example the field viewed in the image, how to save it and how to calculate the view efficiently?[image]

Comment: Wikipedia article: [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do something for your first idea using MERISE.
Yes you might have some views corresponding to you consulting the posts but as a VIEWER. Mabe you might have another association or I may build it differently in function of your project.

Well, I am studying this field this semester, so maybe that is not all perfect.

[image: Idea_1]